# Sidebar disappears in Safari and Mobile Safari

Tags: bug, new-nav, sidebar

The sidebar vanishes when returning to the question list by using the back button or swiping from the left edge of the screen in Mobile Safari on both iPad and iPhone (IOS 9.1) - main SO site and Meta.

[image]

**EDIT**

This is also an issue in Safari 9.0.1 on Mac (El Capitan).

On initial page load, the side bar is visible, it then disappears. You can see from the screenshots below that the sidebar is loaded with the page source but then the `<div id="sidebar"></div>` node is emptied at some point after.

**Source**

[image]

**Node tree**

[image]

Both Chrome and Firefox seem to be unaffected.

I have no content / ad blockers or extensions installed.

Comment: Are you using any content blockers (Settings > Safari > Content Blockers) and, if so, does this persist if you deactivate them?

Comment: I don't believe that option exists in 9.1 - but no, I don't use any sort of content or ad blockers.

Comment: It definitely does; maybe you don't see the option if there are none installed.

Comment: Perhaps so. See edit above - the issue also exist in Safari

Comment: I've never seen this in Safari 9.0 (OS X 10.9.5) or iOS 9.0.x. All stock, no extensions.

Comment: This is still not fixed. Am I the only one seeing this issue?

Comment: Not fixed.  Not seeing this one, I posted the same today: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316259/right-nav-missing.  Very easy to reproduce, surprised that it hasn't had more attention.

Comment: I actually see this issue in Firefox on occasion, though Safari was always having it when I last checked.

Comment: Still happening in iOS 9.3.1. Every single time I navigate back. Rather annoying.

Comment: Reproduced in Chrome on Android.