# Is there a way to "bump" an old meta post?

Tags: discussion, meta

I [posted a bug report](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309651/sidebar-disappears-in-safari-and-mobile-safari) a while back on meta

Despite being confirmed by another user who posted the same bug ([link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316259/right-nav-missing)) it received very little attention from the team.

The bug still exists and I'd like to bring attention to my original post.

What is the correct/acceptable way to "bump" an old post? Is there one? Does editing a post move it back to the top of the list? (I should probably know this by now)

I'm aware that I have essentially brought attention to the post with this one but that is purely a side-effect of my actual question (honest guv').

Comment: Getting it more attention from meta users (by annoying us with superfluous edits) isn't going to get it any more attention from the SE developers.

Comment: That's why I asked for the "correct/acceptable" way rather than just doing it.

Comment: You don't.  That's how.

Comment: Since you are asking about a bug report, keep in mind that the developers can see (and do track) bug reports across all meta sites.  I think they even have a special view to get them all, but can't remember where I saw that.  The fact that a dev edited your question when you originally posted it does mean that it was seen, so likely is on their radar.  You just don't know where it falls in the priority list.

Comment: Ah yes. I hadn't noticed Oden's edit (it was a few months after I posted). Thanks for the info @psubsee2003