# Meta's use-case is different to Stack Overflow's in some ways, and the rules should be changed to reflect that

Tags: discussion

Or to put it simply, *certain* Meta questions should be allowed to be bumped without fear of reprisal. I'm talking in particular about those tagged as [burninate-request](/questions/tagged/burninate-request) and [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request).

For example, [there's a tag burnination request from 3 years ago that never got actioned, but that I believe should be](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287649/dump-the-core). The way the rules currently stand, I have no way to (re-)apply for burnination of that tag, because:

- if I create a new burnination request question - it'll get closed as a dupe of the current one
- if I make a superfluous edit to the existing question, or post a non-answer, in order to bump it to the top of the homepage - my actions will be rolled back
- on SO, a bounty would do the trick - Meta doesn't have bounties

So I literally have no way to (re-)propose burnination of that tag, which to me seems like a pretty serious issue/oversight! The same issue is present for feature requests, which IMO is even more problematic because it means that the SO devs won't get eyes on things that the community considers important.

A simple way to get around this issue would be make questions with those tags behave differently: *an upvote on such a question should bump it to the top of the Meta homepage*.

Your thoughts?

Previously: [Is there a way to "bump" an old meta post?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322569/is-there-a-way-to-bump-an-old-meta-post) which was closed as a duplicate of [On Meta, how do you get attention for questions without an answer?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266782/on-meta-how-do-you-get-attention-for-questions-without-an-answer) even though - as is usual for Meta - it actually isn't a dupe.

Comment: Related: [Why do some burninate request with over 20 votes not get featured?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/356820/7296893). Short answer there: the process of featuring is manual. This specific request has over 20 votes, so might get featured, but there's no clear timeline on it. Iirc there was an effort to order open burnination requests per priority a few months ago.